# Run main form again from Main() with compact framework

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I'm developing application for devices that use Compact Framework of C#. I need to restart my application or run Application.run with main form from Main method again so that it can be updated. I can't use Application.Restart() or just Application.Run() as both aren't available in compact framework. 
I have tried to use:

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
    private static extern bool CeRunAppAtTime(string pwszAppName, DateTime lpTime);
    var time = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(15);
    CeRunAppAtTime(fullAppName, time);
```

but this isn't working. Also tried:

```
rocessStartInfo Info = new ProcessStartInfo();
Info.Arguments = "/C ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 && \"" + fullAppName + "\"";
Info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
Process.Start(Info);
Application.Exit();
```

but this didn't also work and gave Win32Error.

Has anyone got any other idea to try or am I doing something wrong with mentioned solutions? Is there a way to execute Application.Run(MyForm) again after Myform.Close() has been run?

Device I use runs on Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5 Professional CE OS 5.2.29094

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish by restarting the application?  You say "so that it can be updated", but what do you mean by "it"?  I'm thinking there's probably an easier way to do this than trying to restart the entire application.

Comment: My application needs to connect service in server to check if application needs to be updated. My problem is that servers ip is defined in settings by user. So when ip is defined first time i need to check if application needs to be updated. If so i need to restart it so i can change .exe before its run.

Comment: So, basically, what you're doing is reading the IP address from a config file, then restarting your entire application to apply it?  Why don't you just read it into memory, have your main procedure call the thread with whatever the value is, and when it changes, dispose and restart the thread with the new info...  It's a helluva lot easier than restarting your entire application and makes it easier to make simple changes, like when the IP changes...

Answer (score 0):

`CeRunAppAtTime` takes in a `SYSTEMTIME` structure, not a managed DateTime, so your first call is definitely going to fail.

The second looks like you're expecting the CE console to be pretty robust.  Is this a vanilla CE device?  If so, the call probably won't work but why not just call to launch your app?  If it's Windows Mobile, where the OS would prevent a second instance from running, then `cmd.exe` doesn't even exist (nor does `ping`) so that would be a failure point.

Your first path is the route I'd go.  Just fix it so the P/Invoke takes in a long and pass it a SystemTime value instead of a managed `DateTime`.

Comment: I tried using CeRunAppAtTime with SYSTEMTIME by increasing SYSTEMTIME minute value by one.
SYSTEMTIME stime = new SYSTEMTIME();
GetSystemTime(ref stime);
stime.wMinute = (ushort)(stime.wMinute + 1);
CeRunAppAtTime(thisName, ref stime);
CeRunAppAtTime returns true so device should have my application scheduled to run after minute has passed. But after closing my application with Application.Exit() it never starts from schedule. And as far as I know I need to close application as CF won't execute application if its already running.